# Help with SQL Stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I need some help with an SQL stored procedure, I haven't got alot of experience with it.
I have a table "dbo.Lookup_Country". It contains 3 fields: ID, Name, Code.
Now I wrote a stored procedure that retrieves the country name by Code.

```
Select Name from Lookup_Country where Code = @Code
```

I need to adjust the stored procedure so that if there are 0 results it has to see if there are results by searching with ID:

Select Name from Lookup_Country where Id = @Code

So basically I need some kind of 'IF' structure:

```
if (Select Name from Lookup_Country where Code = @Code) == 0 results
      Select Name from Lookup_Country where Id = @Code
```

Is this possible?

thx

Thx for the help everyone, I used this:

```
DECLARE @Name nvarchar(50)

-- Insert statements for procedure here
SET @Name = (SELECT Name from dbo.Lookup_Country WHERE Code = @CODE)
IF @Name != ''
    SELECT Name from dbo.Lookup_Country WHERE Code = @CODE
ELSE
    SELECT Name from dbo.Lookup_Country WHERE ID = @CODE
```

Comment: what engine do you use? ms-sql ,my-sql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the results of the first select into a variable, then you can do a count on that result, and if that is zero then you would do the search by id.

To learn more about how to use the `if` statement then check out this article, if you are using SQL Server, but, if you are using a different database then the logic still applies the `if` syntax may differ.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182587.aspx

Answer (score 4):

There isn't a really elegant way for this...

```
SELECT Name 
INTO #foo
from Lookup_Country where Code = @Code
IF @@ROWCOUNT <> 0
   SELECT Name  FROM #foo
ELSE
   Select Name from Lookup_Country where Id = @Code
```

Whether you use a table variable or count, it doesn't matter

Or you have this construct, perhaps with an aggregate

```
SELECT TOP 1
    Name
FROM
    (
    Select Name, 0 AS Precedence from Lookup_Country where Code = @Code
    UNION ALL
    Select Name, 1 AS Precedence from Lookup_Country where Id = @Code
    ) foo
ORDER BY
    Precedence
```

If you include Precedence in the output you have information on *how* it was found...

Answer (score 0):

Does it help you?

```
 Select Name from Lookup_Country where (Code = @Code OR Id = @Code)
```

Comment: This will return rows with *ID = @Code* even if there exists a row with *Code = @Code*.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably just use an `or`:

```
Select Name from Lookup_Country where Code = @Code or Id = @Code
```